# some questions about complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

1a) Find the largest open disc on which the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \cdot (2z+1)^n $ converges.

1b) Find the function represented by the derivative of this power series.

I already found when it converges but my question is if the function which I have to differentiate is $n\cdot(2z+1)^n$ or an equivalent sum.

2)I have to sketch the curve defined by this equation:$|z + 1| + |z - 1| = r $ for $ r, z \in [2, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}^+ $.

The only thing that cames to my mind is to simplify the expression using $ |z| \ge z $, but I don't know if this correctly produces the sketch.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, if this is HW, it should be tagged as such. Regards

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of #1, you are correct in that you shouldn't just differentiate your given sum and then try to arrive at an equivalent sum. Rather, note that $$\begin{align*} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \cdot (2z + 1)^{n} &= {2z + 1} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \cdot (2z + 1)^{n-1}\\& = \frac{2z + 1} {2} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{d}{dz} (2z + 1)^n \\&= \frac{2z + 1}{2} \cdot\left[ \frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (2z + 1)^n \right] \\&= \frac{2z + 1}{2}\cdot \left[\frac{d}{dz} \frac{1}{1 - (2z + 1)}\right]\\& = \frac{2z + 1}{4z^2} \end{align*}$$.

Hence, its derivative is simply $ \frac{d}{dz} \frac{2z+1}{4z^2} = - \frac{z+1}{2z^3} $.

For #2, you are going to have a piece-wise function with 3 different line segments. Let $r = f(z) $ denote the value of $ r $ as a function of $ z $. Using the basic definition of the absolute value function, $$ f(z) = \begin{cases}-2z &\ z \ < -1 \\\ \ \ 2 & |z| \le\ \ \ 1 \\ \ \ \ 2z & \ z \ > \ \ \ 1 \end{cases} $$